# Spring Data REST - Unrecognized field "_embedded" by consuming list of entities, Java HATEOAS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-hateoas

I am trying to consume a list of entities from the following REST HAL response:

```
    {
  "_embedded" : {
    "posts" : [ {
      "branch" : 1,
      "article" : "aaaaaaa",
      "featuredImage" : "aaaaaaa",
      "authorId" : 1,
      "datePublished" : "2020-05-05T09:11:13.336+0000",
      "commentsEnabled" : true,
      "enabled" : false,
      "views" : 0,
      "snippetTitle" : null,
      "snippetDescription" : null,
      "comments" : null,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8081/posts/1"
        },
        "post" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8081/posts/1"
        },
        "categories" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8081/posts/1/categories"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "branch" : 1,
      "article" : "aaaaaaa",
      "featuredImage" : "aaaaaaa",
      "authorId" : 1,
      "datePublished" : "2020-05-05T10:45:15.999+0000",
      "commentsEnabled" : true,
      "enabled" : false,
      "views" : 0,
      "snippetTitle" : null,
      "snippetDescription" : null,
      "comments" : null,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8081/posts/3"
        },
        "post" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8081/posts/3"
        },
        "categories" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8081/posts/3/categories"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/posts/search/byAuthorId?authorId=1&page=0&size=10"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 10,
    "totalElements" : 3,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

I would like to map these entities to this class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Post {
  private int id;
  private int branch;
  private String article;
  private Date datePublished;
  private String featuredImage;
  private Boolean commentsEnabled;
  private Boolean enabled;
  private int views;
  private String snippetTitle;
  private String snippetDescription;
}
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> Unrecognized field "_embedded" (class
>   org.springframework.hateoas.PagedModel), not marked as ignorable (3
>   known properties: "links", "page", "content"])

With this code:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

  messageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/hal+json"));
  messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

  ResponseEntity<PagedModel<Post>> responseEntity =
    new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(messageConverter)).exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedModel<Post>>() {});
```

**The versions are:**

Jackson-databind version: 2.11.0

Spring-hateoas version: 1.0.5.RELEASE

*Any help would be appreciated!*

Answer (score 0):

Response structure seems like `PagedResources<T>` type.

Use `org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources` in `ParameterizedTypeReference`

```
ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Post>> responseEntity =
    new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(messageConverter)).exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<Post>>() {});
```

Comment: Hello Eklavya,

Thanks for your reaction, been very busy so didn't have much time to implement your solution.

I tried your solution, but PagedResources has been renamed to PagedModel according to this link: https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/05/spring-hateoas-1-0-m1-released

Comment: Which spring-boot version are you using ? is it compatible with Heteos. Currently you can't use `PagedResources` right ?

Comment: this solution does n to work. PagedResources is already deprecated with PagedModel and I got the same error